# If statement error. Comparison of numbers to output max

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a simple code on python, but have come across an unusual error. The statements are to compare thre numbers and return the max value. Most of the time the program executes fine, however, if for example num3 is a 3-digit number and others are not, I get a comparison error. Any ideas?

```
def maxNum(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num3 and num2 >= num1:
        print (num2)
        return num2
    else:
        print (num3)
        return num3

num1 = input("Please enter first number: ")
num2 = input("Please enter second number: ")
num3 = input("Please enter third number: ")
print ("Max number is:", maxNum(num1, num2, num3))
```

Please click on image link. I have changed the code as advised but still get error. It seems any integer that I input that is more than or equal to 100 creates this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXGqu.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever think about how the possibilities of that else? It now only consider the cases of n3, which can be less than or greater than any of the other numbers. Also that else consider the other cases that your previous if not. For example that n1 is less than n2 but bigger than n3. I will go for something simple `max = n1` then `max = (max >= n2)? max : n2` and finally `max = (max >= n3)? max : n3`... and then just return `max`

Comment: `input` gives you a string. Even if that string contains numeric characters, it's still a string. Comparison will be done *lexically*, not numerically. Convert the input to a number (hint: `int()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  1 def max_num(num1, num2, num3): 
  2     biggest = max([int(num1),int(num2), int(num3)]) 
  3     return biggest  
  4     
  5 num1 = input("Enter First Number: ") 
  6 num2 = input("Enter Second Number: ") 
  7 num3 = input("Enter Third Number: ") 
  8  
  9  
 10 print(max_num(num1, num2, num3))
```

Are you just trying to work the function comparisons, or are you open to other methods?
This will accomplish the same task with less steps.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am by no means fluent in Python, I believe the approach to distinguish all cases that can occur is hard to understand. Instead, I suggest iterating the input values as follows. The approach uses an additional varaiable to store the potential result.

```
def maxNum(num1, num2, num3):
    result = num1
    if (num2 > result)
        result = num2
    if (num3 > result)
        result = num3
print(result)
return result
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please check image ive uploaded, changes made as suggested. But still gives this bug.